# Jquery hide of nested Primefaces panelGrid not selecting grid element

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I can't select the datagrid element with my form using the below. If I just do #dreamModifyFrm without any child element it will hide it.  If I wrap a panel or div or ul around the dataGrid and use that in the selector (#panelId) then it will hide it. Anyone know how to select the grid in Jquery?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
                   $ = jQuery;
                   $(document).ready(function() {
                           $("#dreamModifyFrm:topTenGrd").hide();
                   });
               </script>
</head>
<body>
<h:form id="dreamModifyFrm" binding="#{dreamModify.dreamModifyFrm}">
<p:dataGrid id="topTenGrd" var="dream" value="#{dreamModifyBean.topDreams}"</dataGrid>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try;

$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('dreamModifyFrm:topTenGrd')).hide();